# Access input files[] using ngModel

Tags: angular

I have an image upload input in my form:

```
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]="item.image" name="image" #image>
```

Is it possible to access `#image.files[0]` using `item.image` ngModel (instead of creating a reference)?

If not, what does ngModel stores anyway when the input type is `file`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to access #image.files[0] using item.image ngModel (instead of creating a reference)?

Yes, you can subscribe to the `change` event of the input and pass the file to the method:

```
<input type="file" name="image" (change)="fileSelected($event.target.files[0])" />
```

> What does ngModel stores anyway when the input type is file?

Nothing. [DefaultValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/DefaultValueAccessor-directive.html)  does not work with `input[type="file"]` and I don't think there is a specific value accessor for it at the moment.